vba: chart line formating
I am building a VBA routing that allows me to set the transparency of lines to 75% by iterating thru all the lines in the chart.  However i am struggling with the fact that only the first series is changed and the other series are unchanged.
Here is the code:
Sub SetLineTransparency()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the chart to the active chart
    Set cht = ActiveChart

    ' Loop through each series in the chart
    For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
        ' Set the line transparency
        With srs.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Transparency = 0.75 ' transparency
        End With
    Next srs
    
End Sub


cht.FullSeriesCollection maybe?

I saw the same thing.  Adding .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0 made it work for me.

I saw the same thing in my testing.
Adding
.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
before setting the transparency made it work for me.
